# Embed function inside onclick

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

I have an onclick function that I"m attempting to modify.

```
onclick="window.location='add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=123&qty=1'"
```

I'm attempting to dynamically set the quantity parameter (qty=) based on the contents of an input form.

The input field:

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="qty-123" value="1" class="txtBoxStyleProd">
```

I'm attempting to do something like:

```
onclick="window.location='add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=123&qty=' document.getElementById('qty-123');"
```

But this breaks the button and does not work. I come from a Java background, and am pretty new to javascript... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's breaking (based on your provided example) because you are not concatenating a string, but rather stating a string and then an element.

Try something more like `"document.location.href = 'add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=123&qty=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('qty-123').value);"` This will get the value from within the input field and concatenate it onto the url you are trying to navigate to.

Further: I would recommend this be done in a function outside of the element for tidiness. Then you can use `onclick="MyRedirectFunction()"`

Comment: You really should be escaping data for the URL.

Comment: As an aside: Make sure you validate the IDs and values you are getting from the URL. Sanitize and parameterize if they are being used in database queries.

Comment: @RobHardy I'm assuming the CMS is already handling that aspect... I'm just modifying a product category page to have an add-to-cart feature on that page instead of having to drill into the product page itself. that URL already functions on the site for other stuff, so presumably, it's being sanitized in the ASP system.

Comment: @SnakeDoc How would your CMS have any bearing on your URL concatenation?  It doesn't.  You must handle that yourself.

Comment: @Brad I was referring to the parameters that were being passed into the .ASP function behind-the-scenes on the server (CMS) side. I have no control over that part, but presumably they are escaping/sanitizing input in the ASP functions... i hope.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, Sanitizing has nothing to do with it, and the problem isn't server-side.  You need to prevent reserved characters from being misinterpreted in the URL.

Comment: @Brad oh I get your point now (sorry, i'm a server guy, not a web guy lol). I'm using the `encodeURIComponent()` function as suggested by you and RobHardy... that should suffice right?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to concatenate and get the value

```
onclick="window.location='add_cart.asp?quick=1&item_id=123&qty=' +  document.getElementById('qty-123').value;"
```

Comment: You really should be escaping data for the URL.

Comment: @Brad can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean exactly?

Comment: @SnakeDoc Use `encodeURIComponent()` around any variable data used as a value in a query string.  Otherwise, reserved characters won't be escaped correctly.  Suppose you wanted the value of something to include `&` or `=`.